# Insert list in sqlite table with django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I am new to Django and I need some help. I am trying to make sqlite3 database with Djnago. I have created class in models.py, which looks like this:

```
 class Data(models.Model):
       vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       versions = models.TextField()
       description = models.TextField()
       date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I am trying to insert list of data in field named versions. List looks like this:

```
['8.0.1', '8.0.2', '8.0.3', '8.1.2']
```

At the end I would like to check, if list contains specific value, for example I would like to check if list contains 8.1.2. If value is in list it should return True. I am able to insert data in database like this:

```
   data = Data(vendor_name='paloalto', product_name='PA', versions=['8.0.1', '8.0.2', '8.0.3', '8.1.2'], description='...')
   data.save()
```

I do not know how to check if database contain specific value in versions field, I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new entity Versions. Then make a 1 to n relationship between Data and Versions

```
class Data(models.Model):
   vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)       

class Versions(models.Model):
     data = models.ForeignKey(Data)
     version = models.CharField()

def query():
    Versions.objects.filter(data__vendor_name='lala', version=3)
```

Comment: How can I insert values from the list to the table?

Comment: You crate Version objects and save them. You have 2 database tables now. Read a bit about relationships in the django models docs.